# Why is my IAM policy getting Access Denied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, amazon-iam

[I'm following this tutorial to a tee on how to grant single user access to a bucket.](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke)

My policy looks exactly like theirs :

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
      "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
      "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["home/${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
       "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
       "Action":["s3:*"],
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company/home/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the username `bob` with the policy properly saved to his IAM account.

I can log into the account and see all my available buckets with `bob` as a user. But if I try to access the bucket, `my-company`, I get `Site says : Access Denied`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some third party S3 clients issuing a ListBucket request to list the bucket root without a supplying a "prefix" at all. This results in an "Access Denied" as the policy in [this blog post](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-west-2#users) expects the "prefix" to be either "", "home/" or the users home directory, not absent entirely.

If you encounter such an issue, adding the following block authorizes this request.

The fix :

```
{
      "Sid": "AllowRootListingWithoutPrefix",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-company"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "s3:prefix": "true"
        },
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:delimiter": [
            "/"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```